# How to check the state of a Linux socket file descriptor?

Tags: linux, windows, sockets, linux-kernel, file-descriptor

In Windows you have "SOCKET_ERROR" and "INVALID_SOCKET" But reading the socket documentation for Linux all i could find is STDERR_FILENO but that seems to be for any file descriptor and not specific to socket file descriptors. so i don't think that would be useful for determining the state of a Linux socket file descriptor.

Here's some Windows socket code for an example:

```
// create a socket for connecting to a server
ConnectSocket = socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype, ptr->ai_protocol);
    if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        WSACleanup();
        fclose(fName);
        return 4;
    }
```

Comment: There are only two states - socket exists or does not exist... I don't understand. What "state" you want to check with socket? What do you want to check? `STDERR_FILENO` is just equal to `2`, it's the file descriptor associated with `stderr` FILE* stream. Maybe you want to poll the socket for `POLLHUP` and `POLLERR`.

Comment: What do you mean by "state of a linux socket file descriptor"? Which exactly info you want to obtain?

Comment: Read [socket(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html), relavant [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) -several of them are related to [BSD sockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets), and [errno(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html)

Comment: `SOCKET_ERROR` and `INVALID_SOCKET` are both defined as -1.  Socket functions like `socket()`, etc return -1 on error.  If a socket is valid, it is not -1. That is your status check for a socket file descriptor.